# Does this use of Monitor.Wait/Pulse have a race condition?

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor, race-condition, pulse

I have a simple producer/consumer scenario, where there is only ever a single item being produced/consumed. Also, the producer waits for the worker thread to finish before continuing. I realize that kind of obviates the whole point of multithreading, but please just assume it really needs to be this way (:

This code doesn't compile, but I hope you get the idea:

```
// m_data is initially null

// This could be called by any number of producer threads simultaneously
void SetData(object foo)
{
    lock(x)                      // Line A
    {
        assert(m_data == null);
        m_data = foo;
        Monitor.Pulse(x)         // Line B
        while(m_data != null)
            Monitor.Wait(x)      // Line C
    }
}

// This is only ever called by a single worker thread
void UseData()
{
    lock(x)                      // Line D
    {
        while(m_data == null)
            Monitor.Wait(x)      // Line E
        // here, do something with m_data
        m_data = null;
        Monitor.Pulse(x)         // Line F
    }
}
```

Here is the situation that I am not sure about:

Suppose many threads call SetData() with different inputs.
Only one of them will get inside the lock, and the rest will be blocked on Line A.
Suppose the one that got inside the lock sets **m_data** and makes its way to Line C.

Question: Could the Wait() on Line C allow another thread at Line A to obtain the lock and overwrite **m_data** before the worker thread even gets to it?

Supposing that doesn't happen, and the worker thread processes the original **m_data**, and eventually makes its way to Line F, what happens when that Pulse() goes off?

Will only the thread waiting on Line C be able to get the lock? Or will it be competing with all the other threads waiting on Line A as well?

Essentially, I want to know if Pulse()/Wait() communicate with each other specially "under the hood" or if they are on the same level with lock().

The solution to these problems, if they exist, is obvious of course - just surround SetData() with another lock - say, lock(y).
I'm just curious if it's even an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the consumer will be enqueued on the waiting or ready queue before another producer.
C# and Java style monitors are described on [Wikipedia, under "Implicit condition monitors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Implicit_condition_monitors).
A nice overview of what happens in `Monitor` (taken from [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) excellent site):
[image]

> "Could the Wait() on Line C allow another thread at Line A to obtain the lock and overwrite m_data before the worker thread even gets to it?"

Suppose that `SetData()` is called by two producer threads, **P1** & **P2**.
A consumer thread, **C1** is started as well.
**P1**, **P2** and **C1** all enter the ready queue.
**P1** acquires the lock first.
The waiting queue is empty, `Pulse()` on `line B` has no effect.
**P1** waits on `line C`, so it is placed on the waiting queue.
The next thread in the ready queue acquires the lock.
It can equally be **P2** or **C1** - in the first case, the assertion fails.
You have a race condition.

> "Supposing that doesn't happen, and the worker thread processes the original m_data, and eventually makes its way to Line F, what happens when that Pulse() goes off?"

It will move a waiter from the waiting queue to the ready queue.
The lock is held by the thread that issues the `Pulse()`.
The notified thread will *get a chance* to acquire the lock after the pulsing thread releases the lock (there can already be others in the ready queue).
From [MSDN, Monitor.Pulse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.pulse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):
*"The thread that currently owns the lock on the specified object invokes this method to signal the next thread in line for the lock. Upon receiving the pulse, the waiting thread is moved to the ready queue. When the thread that invoked Pulse releases the lock, the next thread in the ready queue (which is not necessarily the thread that was pulsed) acquires the lock."*

> "Will only the thread waiting on Line C be able to get the lock? Or will it be competing with all the other threads waiting on Line A as well?"

All threads that are on the ready queue "compete" for having the lock next.
It does not matter if they got there straight or from the waiting queue by means of `Pulse()`.

<sub>The "queues" might be implemented by other means. (Not the *queue* data structure as such).

This way a `Monitor` implementation may not guarantee fairness  - but may have higher overall throughput/performance.</sub>